# Java stream question, mapToInt and average method

Tags: java, java-stream, average

Why can I call `average()` method on one but not on the other? Shouldn't they be equivalent?

example 1 - works

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("2");
    stringList.add("4");
    stringList.add("6");
// String array ("2","4", "6"
averageValue = stringList.stream()
                .mapToInt(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
```

example 2 - doesn't compile (deleted mapToInt call because already passing Integer stream)

```
List<Integer> IntegerList = new ArrayList<>();
        IntegerList.add(2);
        IntegerList.add(4);
        IntegerList.add(6);

averageValue = IntegerList.stream()
                    .average()
                    .getAsDouble();
```

Question, is why do I need to call mapToInt method when Im already passing it a stream of Integers?

Comment: Nit: use `Integer.parseInt` instead of `valueOf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two *different* types: a `Stream<Integer>` and an `IntStream`.

Java's generics can't have methods that only apply on *some* generics.  For example, it couldn't have `Stream<Integer>.average()` and not *also* have `Stream<PersonName>.average()`, even though the average person name doesn't make sense.

Therefore, `Stream` has a `mapToInt` method that converts it into an `IntStream`, which then provides the `average()` method.

Comment: I see, correct me if i didnt understand you, so theoretically it would be logical for 
IntegerList.stream().average() to work, but since it would not work for all possible inputs, therefore breaking how template works, i still have to apply MapToInt method to ItegerStream to get access to average method?

Comment: Thank you, it did clarify the confusion for me.

Answer (score 4):

`IntStream` provides `average()` method, so to use it you need to convert `Stream<Integer>` to `IntStream` by using `mapToInt` method.